# Backbone JS Event from child view not firing

Tags: backbone.js

I'd gone through most of the solution for this issue but still couldn't solve it. Please help me guys. T.T
My child event is not firing no matter how I configure it please guide me through it.
My parent is 'dayInfo' and I'm calling 'schedule' from the parent.
But the html button is not triggering the event.

///// schedule.html /////

```
<a class="ic-plus-circle add"></a>
```

///// schedule.js /////

```
define(function(require) {

var Backbone        = require('backbone'),
    User            = require('models/User'),
    css             = require('text!views/dayInfo/schedule.css'),
    tpl             = require('text!views/dayInfo/schedule.html');

return Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {

        this.template       = _.template(tpl);

        var self = this;

        return this;
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;

    self.$el.html(self.template());

        return this;
    },

    events: {

        'tap .add': function(e) {
            console.log('success');
            var self = this;
            var $this = $(e.currentTarget);

            console.log('tapped');                  
        }
    }
});
});
```

////// dayInfo.html /////

```
<div class="tab-content"></div>
```

////// dayInfo.js /////

```
define(function(require) {

var Backbone        = require('backbone'),
    ScheduleView    = require('views/dayInfo/schedule'),
    css             = require('text!views/dayInfo/dayInfo.css'),
    tpl             = require('text!views/dayInfo/dayInfo.html');

return Backbone.View.extend({

    id : 'dayInfo',

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.template               = _.template(tpl);

        var self = this;

        return this;
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this;

        self.$el.html(self.template());

        self.$tabContent = self.$el.find('.tab-content');

        self.scheduleView = new ScheduleView({date:self.date,doctor:self.doctor,appointments:self.appointments,events:self.events}).render();
        self.$tabContent.html(self.scheduleView.$el);
    }
});
});
```

I was expecting the console to throw 'tapped' whenever I click the button

Comment: `var self = this;` is completely useless everywhere you used it. It's one of the trick to keep the context when using function expression, but you're not using any callback. See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1218980)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `tap` event, which is why it's not firing. See [MDN - Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) for list of available touch events.

You'll need to get a touch event plugin what works with jQuery to have custom events such as `tap`

Comment: found the issues bro. Thanks a lot XD